# How is $π$ irrational if.....

Tags: pi

If we take a rope of length $x$ which is rational quantity and we make a circle out of it, we measure its diameter which is also rational, if we divide a rational number by another rational number we should get a rational number but the division of length of circumference and diameter should give $π$ which is irrational...?

Comment: When you do that you get an approximate of $\pi$ not the actual value of $\pi$.

Comment: "we measure its diameter which is also rational" : you measure a rationa approximation of the diameter.

Comment: If the circumference is rational then the diameter is not.

Comment: We **know** the $\pi$ is irrational because we prove it be so, **not** because we have measured it. The distinction between *mathematics* and land surveying was discovered by Ancient Greeks.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. So you can only ask questions here if you know enough math to not need to ask them, huh?

Answer (score 6):

When you *measure* the length of something or the diameter of a circle in real life it *looks* like some rational number ... but that doesn't mean it is. In real life you just can't get any *precise* measurement of something.

And don't forget that math is an abstraction ... Lines in math have no thickness, whereas ropes in real life do; so how exactly would you even measure the diameter when laying the rope in a circle?

Answer (score 3):

The diameter will not be rational. It will be a rational number divided by $\pi$.

Comment: Or approximately so, anyway; remembering that we're talking about the diameter of a rope circle the measurement is not going to be very exact.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer OP needs. Talking about the distinction between a measurement and the true value of something just seems like it might confuse them.